# When does the "Entrepreneurial Gap" become just poor management?

Tags: management, work-environment, leadership

I can find lots of articles and information about how wonderful the "entrepreneurial gap" is for stimulating creativity and innovation, and how to do it (increasing "span of influence" and decreasing "span of control"), but I find nothing about intended duration, warning signs its not working, risks, and how to determine when it is NOT a best practice.

My specific questions are:

Can an "Entrepreneurial Gap" go on for too long?

What are some specific indicators that it ISN'T working and either span of control or span of influence needs adjustment?

What are some factors that would contraindicate the creation of an "entrepreneurial gap" as a viable option to increase productivity/success?

Are there risks involved? Is employee burn-out and frustration a risk? How can it be mitigated?

I'm asking because I suspect a long time ago (ten years) a leader who is long gone implemented this at my company, and due to nearly constant reorganizations, realignments, and "focus shifting" which has shuffled several leaders in an out and has resulted in my department being tossed about like a hot potato, or a "red headed step child" (no personal offense to the red haired folk or those with blended families intended!) We are now desperately understaffed and have become siloed (which is the opposite of the intended effect.) We suffer from "bad management" now, but it hasn't always been this way, and I don't think anyone foresaw how bad things could get.

I am working with two others in my department to come up with a  plan to rebuild it. We've hit rock bottom, and we have yet another new leader coming in and another re-org has just kicked off.  We're hoping that we can ride the wave of upheaval and use it as an opportunity to turn things around, starting with the staffing problem (understaffing is not the only trouble here-its just the most glaring offender.)  I'd like to understand this theory better, but know literally NO ONE who even knows what it is, let alone has any experience (good or bad, from a leadership or employee perspective.) I think the conversation might be more productive if I and my team members can see this from "the view from the top" perspective, and tune our evidence/facts accordingly.

This is my first question here-please forgive any errors in form/content.

For those unfamiliar with what it is, here’s a link:

https://www.hbs.edu/ris/Publication%20Files/13-100_2d6016b2-6861-478c-a488-98ca7d71ba53.pdf

Comment: It sounds to  me like you ought to maneuver yourself into a **management** position!  Maybe some of those folks could ... seriously ... benefit from your insights. // As someone who has over these many years "sat on both sides of that desk," I am actually utterly serious. (P.S.: "The other side" can sometimes be *lonelier ...)*

Comment: Well, I appreciate the sentiment, but one of the other issues we face is a lack of mobility or any opportunity for development. We do not have career paths. I got my hands on the job descriptions and they are IDENTICAL at each level, with the exception of a position I’ve never even heard of. How can that be? It’s asinine. The only way one can move from one position to another is if someone retires or dies. Even then, you just get to do their work plus your own. Your title may change but not pay. Its dismal. I’ll turn 40 soon and I’m doing the same thing I was @26. :-(

Comment: I've never heard of an "entrepreneurial gap", and frankly, I'm not even sure I want to know what it means. Please just tell us what kind of company this is. Is this a growing company with a growing martket? or is it a company that thrives on streamlining and cost-cutting? What about your department? Does it earn revenue for your company?

Comment: Anytime people start using long buzzwords to explain vague concepts it's broken.

Comment: @Stephan Branczyk I work at an internationally owned utility company. We are regulated because we are basically a monopoly. So, we can only charge our customers what we can prove to regulators it costs to run the company. We make money by “investing” in infrastructure and doing so under budget, basically. Our region is experiencing growth (new customers coming in due to development of land and businesses, as well as solar and wind.) My department secures and manages land and land rights. We don’t *directly* earn revenue, but contribute to it indirectly by supporting depts that do.

Comment: @Kilisi I agree. “Entrepreneurial Gap” is a fancy way of saying “sink or swim,” in my experience. I find that the people who use the most buzzwords are the ones who know the least real words to describe what they are doing, what their direct reports are doing, and what the company is doing. They’re banking on us lowly peasants not having the time or intelligence to read such lofty publications as the Harvard Business Review. Do I sound disdainful? I am. I have so much patience, but none for incompetent, willfully negligent people in leadership positions. Step down and go away.

Comment: @Jax, Your department is a cost center, not a revenue generator. I really doubt the situation is going to improve for you if you stay there. What's keeping you there? A nice pension?

Comment: “Land management” includes leasing company property, so I partially disagree we are entirely a cost center. We def make money doing that. Why do I stay? Overall, the company has an excellent culture, pay and benefits are great, and I have not found another position that comes close to this one in terms of compensation and match for my skills/experience/education/interest. Ive gotten offers...none that would be a feasible option. I do have mouths to feed. The bad management part...comes from 1-2 individuals in my group’s leadership. Not the entire company.

Comment: Re: "'entrepreneurial gap'... [I] know literally NO ONE who even knows what it is". If that's the case, then shouldn't you explain/link/provide a reference to what it is in your question?

Comment: @Daniel R. Collins link to pdf explaining the concept added.

Comment: Thanks for a step in that direction, but that really doesn't suffice on this site (or really anywhere). Normal reference practice is a summary in 1-3 sentences, not simply a link that can bitrot away, nor asking the reader to digest a 55 page paper before being able to help you.

Comment: Follow-up question, re: "I'm asking because I **suspect** a long time ago (ten years) a leader who is long gone implemented this at my company" (emphasis mine) So does anyone else at your company even talk about this management theory? Is it explicit in your company/division, or is this something you've found out about separately and seek to apply on your own? I suspect this is just an overly-roundabout way of your saying "we are under-resourced".

Comment: Jax, in trying to answer your question I find that I don't understand enough of how you would define the entrepreneurial gap and what aspects of that definition are and aren't at play in the organization you work in. That paper is *really* broadly worded and leaves a lot open to interpretation. Without a 'working definition' to guide us, I'm not sure you'll get an answer that's specific to your organization.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, it seems you're fixated on this methodology, when it appears it's long been cast aside by those in upper management and instead you're just left with bog-standard under-resourcing (and yes, just general mismanagement).

I think it's time you just make the assumption that whatever remnants of that organisational structure that remain are no longer serving the interests of the team, and work with your colleges and develop and ground up approach, as you are doing.

You can certainly get mired in some academic assessment of where it all went wrong, but given you not-so-flattering assessment of upper management, it seems the effort world be wasted.